# Finding C in a definite integral with no reference point

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, constants

How to find C in this equation?

$$\int_0^x f(t)~dt=\int_x^1t^2f(t)~dt + x^2/4 + x^4/8 +C$$

I attempted to move over $\int_0^x f(t)~dt$ to the right side, so that I could solve a definite integral for x, but the signs (it would become negative) don't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should took the derivative of the equation to obtain $$ f(x) = -x^2f(x) + \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^3}{2}, $$ so $f(x) = \frac{x+x^3}{2(1+x^2)}$. Now use that in the equation to obtain $$ \frac{x^2}{4} = \frac{1}{8} - \frac{x^4}{8} + \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{x^4}{8} + C .$$ Then $C=-\frac{1}{8}$.

Comment: Lost you at the last step– I got the same for f(x), but what is the last equation you used? What are you plugging in?

Comment: @gticecream8 now that you now $f(x)$ you have to solve the integrals. The function is finally $f(x) = x/2$, so it is easy to compute those definite integrals.

Comment: Are you taking the integrals, from the very first original equation? Ex: integral of f(x) from 0 to x on the left side, and fill in f(x) with the new equation?

Comment: @gticecream8 Exactly. That will give you the last step of my answer.

Comment: to be clear, you took the integral of (x+x^3)/(2(1+x^2)) from 0 to x on the right side, and the integral of x^2*(x+x^3)/(2(1+x^2)) from x to 1, on the left side? Is it supposed to be a super long process, with u substitutions etc?

Comment: I did that, but as I mentioned, $f(x) = (x+x^3)/(2(1+x^2)) = x/2$ (because we are working on the real numbers), so the integrals are much easier than you thought.

Comment: ah, thank you so much. Makes perfect sense now!